# using own styles, changes behaviour of "below = of"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

While drawing a program flowchart I encountered a problem regarding the "below = of"/ "below of =" behavior.
I Would like to place two nodes beneath each other with a fix distance from edge to edge.

I'm using the tikzlibrary "positioning" to do so, the result however changes if I use my own style.

minimal example:

```
\documentclass[border=1in]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}

     \tikzset{
         pap/.style={
             draw,
            minimum height=7mm,
            font=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
            align=flush center,
            on grid
        },
    }
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {A};
  \node [pap,below = of a] {C};
  \node [pap,below of = a] {D};
  \node [right of = a] (a2) {A2};
  \node [below = of a2] {C2};
  \node [below of = a2] {D2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

results in:
[image]

where I would expect the left side to be as the right side.

Sorry for my poor English, I would appreciate any help.
Best Regards, 
Jannis

Comment: Welcome! What happens if you remove `on grid`?

Comment: Thats it!
That was easy, i was searching more than an hour before :(

Comment: `on grid` forces positioning onto a grid .... :-)

Comment: makes totally sense, I guess I'm just to tired :(
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can see all the result details for positioning in this document [7.11 Positioing relative to nodes](http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf#subsection.7.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on grid` forces positioning onto a grid. If you want to specify the position of nodes exactly, that's not what you want.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  pap/.style={
    draw,
    minimum height=7mm,
    font=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    align=flush center,
  },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {A};
  \node [pap,below = of a] {C};
  \node [pap,below of = a] {D};
  \node [right of = a] (a2) {A2};
  \node [below = of a2] {C2};
  \node [below of = a2] {D2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: not on a grid]